# How to pass two arguments with one variable into a function?

Tags: python, function, arguments, priority-queue

I have been given a class which  implements a Priority Queue , using a function to evaluate the priority.

```
class PriorityQueueWithFunction(PriorityQueue):
    """
    Implements a priority queue with the same push/pop signature of the
    Queue and the Stack classes. This is designed for drop-in replacement for
    those two classes. The caller has to provide a priority function, which
    extracts each item's priority.
    """
    def  __init__(self, priorityFunction):
        # type: (object) -> object
        "priorityFunction (item) -> priority"
        self.priorityFunction = priorityFunction      # store the priority function
        PriorityQueue.__init__(self)        # super-class initializer

    def push(self, item):
        "Adds an item to the queue with priority from the priority function"
        PriorityQueue.push(self, item, self.priorityFunction(item))
```

I have been also , given , the priority function that I am going to initialize the class above with.

```
def manhattanHeuristic(position, problem, info={}):
    "The Manhattan distance heuristic for a PositionSearchProblem"
    xy1 = position
    xy2 = problem.goal
    return abs(xy1[0] - xy2[0]) + abs(xy1[1] - xy2[1])
```

The above code is given to us and we cannot change it. I must create that PriorityQueueWithFunction Class and push an element to it. The **push** function of my class takes on argument , the item. But my PriorityFunction takes 2. 
What kind of arguments should i use to push the right elemnt into my class and also make my priorityfunction work properly ?

That's what i tried and i am getting compiling errors , *manhattanHeuristic...takes 2 arguments , 1 given*

```
#Creating a queingFn
queuingFn = PriorityQueueWithFunction(heuristic)
Frontier = queuingFn
#Creating the item that needs to be pushed
StartState = problem.getStartState()
StartNode = (StartState,'',0,(-1,-1))
#Here is my problem
item = StartState , problem
Frontier.push(item)
```

Should I change my item's form ? Any ideas ?

Comment: take a look at `*args` and `**kwargs`. They allow you to pass an arbitrary amount of data in a function using a single (or two) variables. You can unpack those then inside the function.

Comment: In your case, it should probably be as simple as adding a star `*` infront of the `item`.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a new method that wraps call to manhattanHeuristic:

```
# for item as dict: item = {'position': POS, 'problem': PROBLEM}
def oneArgHeuristic(item):
    position = item.position
    problem = item.problem
    return manhattanHeuristic(position, problem)

# for item as tuple: item = (POS, PROBLEM)  
def oneArgHeuristic(item):
    position, problem = item
    return manhattanHeuristic(position, problem)
```

and pass it to `PriorityQueueWithFunction` instead of the original one